# What is "{.tmp,app} " in Yeoman generator?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am getting started with the Yeoman workflow, but I can't seem to completely understand the "alternate search path" for the usemin task in the index.html file. For example, there are 2 blocks generated with the 'yo angular' command:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/modules.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

vs.

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/multiselect.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Why does the second one have the {.tmp, app} "alternate search path" (what does it mean)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

In yeoman js scripts are available in the `app` folder, but when the user is using `CoffeeScript` grunt task will convert `.coffee` files to `.js` files. Those generated `.js` files will be available in `.tmp` folder with the same folder structure.

In those condition `({.tmp,app})` is used to tell grunt-usemin to search both in **app** and **.tmp** folder, so that the build won't miss out generated js files.

`scripts/scripts.js` is the destination file after the build.

Comment: I'm assuming the same goes for SCSS files?

Comment: That's interesting. Also, this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18847100/1446845) gives some additional info about how the local server serves the content from the `tmp` folder.